# Django REST Framework: Is it possible to implement after the complete development of a website?

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie and currently developing a Django website, I want to know whether I should implement REST framework now for each app or should I do it after completing the whole website? Which is the easiest or the most proffered way and is it easy to implement?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on the project and the methodology you use. If you are going to need pages that hit the API, you will have to create at least some methods before finishing the website, but if you just want to provide an API to third-party applications or whatever, it is up to you when you want to do this.

Sometimes I think it would be better to complete an APP including the serializers and API views before starting another one, as you will have every fresher and it could take time more time to do it when you have finished the whole website, as you might not remember some of your implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This may get closed for being an opinion-oriented question, but I will try to answer regardless.

Your best bet would be to fully develop and test the website first, and then implement the Rest Framework. Your database design, models and functionality will likely change drastically from what you expected, so it would cause many alterations if you were to develop the REST API alongside the initial development.

Comment: Thank you for the response.